# Unable to import oracle dump in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to import oracle dump in Oracle 11g XE by using the below command

```
imp system/manager@localhost file=/home/madhu/test_data/oracle/schema_only.sql full=y
```

Getting like below

```
IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Any one please help me

Comment: A dump file wouldn't normally have a `.sql` extension; was your file actually produced by `exp`, and if so was it on the same platform and Oracle version? If not how was it generated, and is it actually just a series of SQL statements in a script?

Answer (score 1):

You received IMP-00037 error because of export file corrupted. I'd suspect either your dump file is corrupted or the dump file was not created by exp utility.

If the issue was occured because of corrupted dump file, then there is no choice other than obtaining uncorrupted dump file. Use impdp utility to import if you have used expdp utility to prepare dumpfile.

Following link will be helpful to try other option:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/870104?start=0&tstart=0
https://community.oracle.com/message/734478

If you are not sure which command(exp/expdp) was used, you could check log file which was created during dump export. It contains exact command which was executed to prepare the dump file.